# How do I prevent webcam hacks

Tags: security, webcam

I have read on many websites that there is an increasing number of attacks on webcams, based on viruses and similar software that allow third parties to gain control of the webcam of an attacked laptop via a remote access.

Can this happen with Ubuntu? How can one protect oneself from such attacks?

Answer (score 3):

1. It <s>never</s> rarely happens in Ubuntu, because:

   - <s>all</s> the most of the trojans and remote spy tools are programmed for windows systems.
   - If anyone infects you with one of these tools for Linux, it will be interested particularly by you, and will take a very hard work to hack your Linux computer.

   1.1. There is a good collection of fake apps and other resources with malware in Android devices, however, being careful and taking care of the per app permissions shouldn't be any trouble.

   1.2. A good advice for both (Ubuntu and Android) is don't try to download miraculous applications from unknown sources or click on fraud ads.
2. The best hardware solution if you're worried is a good piece of paper or a bit of insulating tape. However I worked with Linux 8 years and **never** had a malware (except self-developed for fun).
3. The most of the websites with *linux virus alarms* are websites authored or contributed by windows users which had white hair of the many scares of main antivirus companies. **;-)**

Comment: 1.1 can this (rarely) happen with android on a smartphone?

Comment: @user126154 I updated the answer